# Running an APP / Script automatically with Lock / Unlock of Screen | KDE

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, kde, gui, automation

So far i have been half successfull with the native notifications menu:

https://i.imgur.com/bUgrxsY.png

I have manage to turn off the screens and close Linphone (Voip APP).

```
/bin/sleep 1 ; /usr/bin/xset dpms force off ; pkill linphone
```

It works perfectly!.

---

However, i cannot manage to reopen linphone by screen unlock, tried this one:

```
nohup linphone &
```

But for some reason, the GUI behaves erratically. f i do "Apply changes", and reopen the same window, the commad is replaced by:

```
/home/user/nohup linphone &
```

Also tried

```
/nohup linphone &
```

With no luck.

Any recomendations?

Related. Tried to run an scrip first to turnOff / close application, but didnt seem to work:

https://i.imgur.com/C963LVs.png

```
  #!/bin/bash
  /bin/sleep 1 ; /usr/bin/xset dpms force off
  pkill linphone
```

(The .sh file has permisions, with the checkbox from the GUI)

Any advice?, thanks!